# How to use a DKO48 telephone microphone?

Tags: telephone, microphone, preamp

I have an old telephone made in the sixties ([FF-OB/ZB or FF53](http://www.cgarbs.de/blog/archives/998-SEL-FF-54-OBZB.html)). Now, I was planning to make an external speaker for that telephone, but I failed miserably, so I've put that aside.

Now, the handset has a headphone, which accepts line levels and I had no problems connecting it to my sound mixer. The Microphone is a different story, though. I know it works correctly, as I can use the telephone without problems. However, when I connect it to the microphone leads (XLR connector) to the sound mixer, which has microphone amplification and phantom power (48V), the microphone appears to have a very weak pickup.

I need to turn up the gain almost to maximum, to get a signal out of it, and at that levels, it acquires huge amounts of static.

The microphone is a [DKO48](http://www.wasser.de/telefon-alt/forum/index.pl?job=thema&tnr=100000000003827&seite=9&begriff=&tin=&kategorie=9-), here's a picture:
[image]

I don't know, whether I should construct a preamp, or if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. In case someone has experience with that sort of thing, please respond.

Comment: I couldn't find any data for the microphone on a Google search, beyond one thing that suggested it was a dynamic microphone.

How do you have the mixer input set up?  High-Z or low?  Balanced or unbalanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC almost all microphones used in telephones were carbon. If this is a carbon microphone (shake it and you should hear a noise of the carbon powder moving around) then you should connect it in series with a speaker and a DC power supply. That's it.

The microphone basically acts like a variable resistor.

If you want to use it to record something (that is, not just for connecting to a loudspeaker), you need to connect it in series with a resistor and a power supply, like this:
[image: schematic]

To protect your equipment from DC offset, connect a small capacitor (10uF or so) in series with the "+" wire.

Comment: OK, cool, I'm gonna rig this up on a breadboard real soon. Just one thing though: It says on a datasheet here, that the DKO48 is a "Transistor microphone capsule" I don't really know what that means, though. I checked the resistance and it's at 80k ohms and dropping (the longer the multimeter was connected, the lower the resistance read).

Comment: I just checked the voltage inside the handset and, it has a DC voltage of 2.8V, so I assume you were correct! I'll check in the morning when I've rigged up the parts on the breadboard.

Comment: @polemon If this is a "transistor microphone" then you should find out which pin is positive and which is negative. It should work in the circuit provided in my answer.

Comment: Have my test setup rigged and it works as expected.